# Where should I put .pem certificate file using Azure Linux App Server for a Node.js/Express.js app?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, ssl-certificate

I have a Node.js application on Azure. I used Express to set it up. I want it to connect to an Azure Database for MySQL. I was able to connect from my development machine using the config option:

```
ssl: {ca: fs.readFileSync("C:\\Path to my\\DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem")}
```

But now I want to connect from a Node.js app on Azure. [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-configure-ssl#step-3--enforcing-ssl-connections-in-azure) shows the code for Node.js using the config option:

```
fs.readFileSync("/var/www/html/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem", "utf8")
```

How do I upload the .pem file into that directory using Azure and Express? I am using Visual Studio Code and can access the file structure, but don't know how to get to /var/www/html or alternatively, put the cert in another safe place.